# How to remove/update single value from array in the database in laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have a column called `userIds` in my database which is an array. I want to be able to update/remove a single value from that array but the methods I have tried has not worked.

**Controller**

```
public function removeUser(Request $request) {
     $scrumId = $request->scrumId;
     $userId = $request->userId;

     DB::table('scrumboards')->where('userIds', $userId)->delete();

     return redirect()->back();
}
```

How would I be able to update a single value from an array from the database without removing the entire column?

--EDIT--

DB row example:

```
title    UserIds
test     ["1"]
```

Comment: Please show us what you mean by `userIds` being an array. Show us an example if possible

Comment: Hi, edited the question above.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a JSON string? If so what version of MySQL are you using

Comment: No, it's supposed to be a regular array. I've edited the model with a cast to make that field an array. I'm using MariaDB (10.4.10-MariaDB).

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad idea to use `userIds`. If your `scrumboards` datas become huge.

It will become so slow when find the scrumboards with `userid`.

### Recommended:

so Why don't you use `hasMany` or `many-to-many` relationship, like `Scrumboard` has many `Users`

and if your datas become huge, you can add index to `scrumboard_id`,

**Scrumboard Model:**

```php
class Scrumboard extends Model {
    protected $table = 'scrumboards';
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'scrumboard_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```php
class User extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function scrumboard()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Scrumboard::class, 'scrumboard_id');
    }
}
```

and then you can delete like this:

```php
User::where('id', $userId)->delete();
# or
User::where('id', $userId)->update(['scrumboard_id' => null]);
```

### Not Recommended:

If you really want to use user_ids, you can do it like this:
(find the user_id by `like`, update it to empty by `replace`)

```php
$sb = DB::table('scrumboards')->where('userIds', 'like', "%\"{$userId}\"%");
$sb->update(['userIds' => \DB::raw("REPLACE(userIds, '\"{$userId}\"', '')")]);
```